# Calories burned program not returning the answer it is supposed to return

Tags: java, int, double

I'm trying to write a simple program from this task.

The number of calories burned per hours by cycling , jogging, and swimming are 200, 475, and 275 respectively. A person loses 1 pound of weight for each 3500 calories burned. Write a program that declares 3 variables, one to store the number of hours spent jogging, the second to store the number of hours spent cycling and the  third to store the number of hours spent swimming. Assign each of these variables values. Calculate and display the number of pounds worked off.

The code I have written is:

```
public class task2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double c = 2; //2 hrs of cycling
        double j = 1; //1 hr of jogging
        double s = 2; //2 hrs of swimming
        double cycle = c * 200; //400 calories
        double jog = j * 475; //475 calories
        double swim = s * 275; //550 calories
        double sum =  cycle + jog + swim / 3500; //1425 / 3500 is what should be in here
        System.out.println("You've burned " + sum + " calories");
    }
}
```

The answer I get back is:

"You've burned 0.40714286 calories"

but I get back:

"You've burned 875.15871428571428 calories".

I don't know where I went wrong. I want the output to be a double so it can show the answer if it's below 3500 calories.

Comment: `/` has precedence over `+`.

Comment: You've made a simple math error (operator precedence).

Comment: In other words, what you currenty have is `cycle + jog + (swim / 3500)`

Answer (score 2):

You might meant: `double sum =  (cycle + jog + swim) / 3500;`

Answer (score 1):

You need () to group all the +'s so that the addition is carried out before the division:

```
double sum =  (cycle + jog + swim) / 3500;
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believed I missed that!